# Case Statement, for loop and if...else in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

In the above column i have unique date.

[image]

I have a drop down list where anything can be selected.. so it has 8 permutation(2^3)..So i want to extract probable date based on the selection..Suppose if i select Year as 2020 and day as 19 then i will extract the probable date which match both the condition..Like above picture...

[image]

Right now i am using 8 if elseif-=...end if statment...and for loop..Is there any other way to do the same work?? I wanted to write a function which will take (day,month,year,lastrow) as parameter and based on probable date will be calculated..Can anyone give me any idea how to do it?

My code now:

```
Public Sub ProbableDate(CaseNo As Integer, lastrow As Long)
Dim sh As Worksheet, sh1 As Worksheet
Set sh1 = Worksheets("Dashboard")
Set sh = Worksheets("Logical operation")
Dim Y As String, M As String, D As String
Y = sh1.Cells(4, 1).Value
M = sh1.Cells(4, 2).Value
D = sh1.Cells(4, 3).Value
Dim L As Long, i As Long
L = 2
With sh
    .Range("H2:H1048576").Clear
    For i = 2 To lastrow
        Select Case CaseNo
            Case 1
                If Year(.Cells(i, 2).Value) = Y Then
                            .Cells(L, 8).Value = .Cells(i, 2).Value
                            L = L + 1
                End If
           Case 2
                If MonthName(Month(.Cells(i, 2).Value)) = M Then
                            .Cells(L, 8).Value = .Cells(i, 2).Value
                            L = L + 1
                End If
           Case 3
                If Day(.Cells(i, 2).Value) = D Then
                            .Cells(L, 8).Value = .Cells(i, 2).Value
                            L = L + 1
                End If
           Case 4
                If Year(.Cells(i, 2).Value) = Y And MonthName(Month(.Cells(i, 2).Value)) = M Then
                            .Cells(L, 8).Value = .Cells(i, 2).Value
                            L = L + 1
                End If
           Case 5
                If Year(.Cells(i, 2).Value) = Y And Day(.Cells(i, 2).Value) = D Then
                            .Cells(L, 8).Value = .Cells(i, 2).Value
                            L = L + 1
                End If
           Case 6
                If Day(.Cells(i, 2).Value) = D And MonthName(Month(.Cells(i, 2).Value)) = M Then
                            .Cells(L, 8).Value = .Cells(i, 2).Value
                            L = L + 1
                End If
           Case 7
                If Day(.Cells(i, 2).Value) = D And MonthName(Month(.Cells(i, 2).Value)) = M And Year(.Cells(i, 2).Value) = Y Then
                            .Cells(L, 8).Value = .Cells(i, 2).Value
                            L = L + 1
                End If
        Case Else
            MsgBox "Wrong Info"
        End Select
    Next i
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Check it now please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify your code using a binary lookup table. Each `CaseNo` matches with a particular set of true/false outcomes for the day, month and year check. These are different to your original mapping, here is the new map:

```
CaseNo  DMY

   0    fail
   1    D
   2     M
   3    DM
   4      Y
   5    D Y
   6     MY
   7    DMY
```

And the code:

```
With sh
    .Range("H:H").Clear
    For i = 2 To lastrow
        OK = 0
        If Day(.Cells(i, 2).Value) = D Then OK = OK + 1
        If MonthName(Month(.Cells(i, 2).Value)) = M Then OK = OK + 2
        If Year(.Cells(i, 2).Value) = Y Then OK = OK + 4
        
        If OK = CaseNo Then
            .Cells(L, 8).Value = .Cells(i, 2).Value
            L = L + 1
        Else
            MsgBox "Wrong Info"
        End If
    Next i
End With
```

Comment: Thanks...I will try it..This idea is so good..I like the idea..

Comment: I think the Elseif OK = 0 then  msgbox is not required as it showing the message each time the data is not matched...Thanks..Please add then keyword and i will accept this answer..this idea is too good..